# Thread suspends itself and another one resumes it afterwards - sometimes second event happens first

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, synchronization

I have two threads; thread 2 provides necessary data for thread 1 and can start working on another piece of data in parallel with thread 1 processing it, but won't move onto the next piece if thread 1 is slower (yes, I'm aware about "Thread 1 reads what Thread 2 writes at the same time", I have a protection in form of two buffers instead of one). The code is below:

```
Thread 1:
while(!shouldexit)
{
    // some code
    Thread1_Ready = true;
    SuspendThread (Thread1_Handle);
}

Thread 2:
while(!shouldexit)
{
    while(!Thread1_Ready)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    // some other code
    ResumeThread(Thread1_Handle);
}
```

The problem is, sometimes the whole code inside Thread 2 happens faster than `SuspendThread` happens in Thread 1. The result is that Thread 1 remains suspended until yet another cycle of Thread 2 passes. This leads to one piece of data not processed by Thread 1 (not very good, but acceptable in my application), and, which is more serious, when the Stop button triggers `shouldexit = true`, Thread 1 just stays in suspended mode indefinitely.

Two possible solutions that I thought of wouldn't work either:
1 - put `Thread1_Ready = true;` after `SuspendThread(Thread1_Handle);` (the code `Thread1_Ready = true;` never executes, obviously)
2 - put the line `SuspendThread(Thread1_Handle);` from Thread 1 to the beginning of Thread 2, right before `// some other code`, but this will cause a delay during which Thread 1 can re-enter the main loop and it will be very unpredictable.

Can this situation be solved differently?

Comment: Busy waiting is not the right way to address this problem. Learn how to use proper synchronization primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a classic [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem). The standard (and in 99% of the cases sufficient) solution is a mutex-protected queue. In your case, the queue size is 1, but the queue semantics still apply.

This will solve your problem because a sample run looks like:

```
Thread 1: Lock queue, see that queue is empty, wait for queue full signal
Thread 2: Produce data
Thread 2: Lock queue, push data into queue (has now size 1), Unlock queue and wake up Thread 1
Thread 2: Produce data
Thread 2: Lock queue, see that queue is full, wait for queue space signal
Thread 1: Wakes up, gets data, sends queue space signal
```

Comment: Thank you, looked at the article, seems very understandable. One question though - are obtaining / releasing a mutex an atomic operation? Because otherwise I'll need a way to ensure that the threads don't enter the critical section (operations with queue) simultaneously.

Comment: @fynjyzn: A mutex (short for mutual exclusion) lock is a mechanism to guarantee atomic operations, so yes, the sequence from obtaining to releasing the mutex is atomic. Since you are using C++, you might want to have a look at Boost.Thread and its condition variables.